# Are translations using Microsoft Translator logged or retained?

Tags: microsoft-translator

Google translate provides this information:

```
Will the text I send to the Cloud Translation API, the results, or other information about the request itself, be stored on Google servers? If so, how long and where is the information kept?
When you send text to Cloud Translation API, we must store that text for a short period of time in order to perform the translation and return the results to you. The stored text is typically deleted after 7 days, but can be temporarily stored up to 14 days in the event of a service failure.
```

But I cannot find any information regarding the Microsoft Translator data storing policies. Does anyone know if Microsoft retains data used in the translation API?

Answer (score 0):

If for business, Microsoft has a "No Trace Policy": https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/business/notrace/. It makes a clear statement about API calls:

"Azure Cognitive Services Translator is a cloud-based machine translation service and is part of the Azure Cognitive Services family of cognitive APIs for building intelligent apps. Customer data submitted for translation to Azure Cognitive Services Translator (both standard and custom models), Speech service, the Microsoft Translator Speech API, and the text translation features in Microsoft Office products are not written to persistent storage. There will be no record of the submitted text or voice, or any portion thereof, in any Microsoft data center. The audio and text will not be used for training purposes either."

On Custom Translator: "Translation requests to your custom models via Translator on Azure are no trace— there will be no record of the submitted text, or portion thereof, in any Microsoft data center."

End user products, same as other providers, do retain some data (typical scenario: you are some consumer using free services). From the same page on No Trace policy:

"The free Microsoft Translator end-user products for which voice clips and text translations are recorded for service improvements purposes are listed below.

Microsoft Translator apps
Translator for Bing
Microsoft Edge
Web Translator"

"Translator apps" above links to a page describing Android and other mobile apps, not to be confused with the Document Translator sample app (https://github.com/MicrosoftTranslator/DocumentTranslator/), which uses whatever Azure Translator cognitive service you have created.